# "The angry man" vs "The man is angry"

Tags: linking-verbs

It seems like existential linking verbs behave like determiners, in that they reference a noun, so I'm curious if there is any actual difference between these 'types' of references.

For example is there a difference in the meaning of the first statement as opposed to the second?

1. "The **angry** man"

-Where 'angry' is an adjective modifying the noun 'man'.

2. "The man is **angry**"

-Where 'angry' is a complement/adjective/abstract-noun

Note: I'm aware that statement one is only a noun phrase while statement two is a clause, so to be clear  I'm asking if the **meaning** between the two is different **not** the **structure**.

Comment: Can you please show two complete sentences using (1) and (2)? If (1) continues as "The angry man looks happy today" then clearly the meaning of "The angry man" isn't the same as "The man is angry".

Comment: Does this statement work or is it grammatically incorrect? "The man is angry but today he looks happy"

Comment: It seems that the OP is asking if there is a semantic difference between a predicative adjective and an attributive adjective. There isn't.

Comment: Without exact context for both usages this is a meaningless question. *Either* constrction could in principle carry the implication of referring to a man who is ***currently angry***. But equally, either construction *could* be used to identify a person who's ***always** or **habitually angry***. And all 4 combinations of construction and meaning can be used either to add information about known referent, ***or*** to uniquely identify the referent (i.e. - as opposed to other men who *aren't* angry).

Comment: See [Attributive and Predicative Adjectives](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/attribut.htm#:~:text=Adjectives%20in%20the%20first%20position,noun%20%2D%20are%20called%20PREDICATIVE%20adjectives.&text=Conversely%2C%20the%20adjective%20afraid%20(the,%3A%20*an%20afraid%20child).). Some adjectives can only be used in one construction (*The **boy** was **afraid**, He is the **main man***, never *The **afraid boy**, The **man** was **main***). But *most* adjectives (including ***angry***) can be used both ways with no difference in meaning.

Comment: The most obvious difference is that "The men is angry has a truth value, whereas "The angry man" does not. The former is true if and only if the individual referred to is, in fact, angry. (or was at the time of utterance, angry.  The latter latter can only contribute to the truth or falsehood if it is the answer to some question (like "who made my child cry?" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to start by examining the semantic (/ pragmatic) roles of adjectives. Those in the attributive position manifest the fullest range. [A paper by Helena Kullenberg](https://www.sol.lu.se/fileadmin/media/forskning/workingpapers/engelska/vol02/Helena.pdf) [slightly modified below] examines Warren's 1984 analysis:

> [During the 1960s - 90s], there [were] sporadic attempts at accounting
> for functions of *attributive adjectives* (Eg Teyssier 1968, Bache
> 1978, Warren 1984a, 1984b, Halliday 1994). One of the most thorough
> and exhaustive studies presented so far [was] probably Warren’s
> Classifying Adjectives (1984a), in which it is suggested that
> premodifying adjectives may **identify**, **classify** or
> **describe**.
>
> Classifiers and identifiers are claimed to differ from descriptors in
> that they somehow restrict the range of the head noun; the former
> restrict semantic range, pointing to a subcategory, and the latter
> restrict reference, indicating a certain referent or group of
> referents within the class denoted by the noun.
>
> An example of a typical **classifier** is *polar* in
>
> - *I saw some polar bears at the zoo*,   where  polar indicates a subcategory within the class of bears.
>
> An example of a typical **identifier** is *red* in
>
> - *Give me the red book*,
>
> where red ’picks out’ the intended referent from the class of books
> (or rather, from a contextually determined set of  books).
>
> **Descriptors**, on the other hand, are seen as optional elements adding extra, nonrestrictive information.
>
> An example of a typical descriptor is *cuddly* in
>
> - *I saw some cuddly teddies*,
>
> where the adjective simply adds descriptive information about the
> teddies in question.

Looking at predicative usages, we see that 'That bear is polar' / 'The reaction is chemical' are not available. Classifier usages must (normally) be attributive.

'The angry man' may be either an identifier or descriptor usage.

As an identifier, it doesn't make sense to have a basic 'The man is angry.' A paraphrase using a defining relative clause such as

'The angry man is the one we suspect.' ↔ 'We suspect the man who is angry.'

is sensible.

As a descriptor,

'The angry man soon left' ↔ 'The man, who was angry, soon left' are paraphrases. And 'The man was / is angry' *is* available here as a simple statement of fact.